# How can Giant-Man access the "realm of the abstract entities"?

Tags: comics, marvel, avengers

When Giant-Man fights the Absorbing Man in Avengers Academy #7 he takes him to the "realm of the abstract entities".  Has it been established how growing or shrinking could take someone to that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, the Pym Particles are a fundamental sub-atomic particle that allows [Hank Pym](http://marvel.com/universe/Yellowjacket_%28Henry_Pym%29) to shrink down and pass into a sub-atomic realm called [Underspace](http://marvel.com/universe/Underspace), and to grow to an abstract level called the Overspace.**

[image]

> Abstract entities like Eternity reside on other planes of existence
>   such as Overspace. The exact polar opposite of that would be
>   Underspace – a plane of reality that lies below the dimension called
>   the Microverse. Underspace is the realm Henry Pym placed his
>   headquarters, the Infinite Avengers Mansion, for his team of Avengers
>   because he discovered his former teammate Thor sent Janet Van Dyne,
>   the original Wasp, there. **--[Underspace](http://marvel.com/universe/Underspace) entry on the Marvel Wikia**

Pym has visited the abstract realm and met Eternity when he went into Overspace.

[image]

> *Never forget this, Hank Pym. You are my champion. You are my avenger!
>   More than a founding Avenger of old, you are the founder of Avengers
>   yet to come. A new Age of Heroes is upon us...more than any being, I
>   put my trust in you. To you I entrust more than myself. To you I
>   entrust the future. But for now, here is what you must do... --
>   [Eternity](http://marvel.wikia.com/Mighty_Avengers_Vol_1_30)*
>
> When Henry Pym grew beyond the macroverse into Overspace, he met
>   Eternity, who thanked him for saving reality from Chthon. He gave the
>   title "[**Scientist Supreme**](http://marvel.wikia.com/Mighty_Avengers_Vol_1_30)" to Pym because of his desire to take science
>   to the point of studying magic. He sent Pym back to Earth, telling
>   him that he was the founder of the Avengers to come and promised a new
>   age of Heroes was coming. **--[Eternity](http://marvel.wikia.com/Eternity_%28Earth-616%29) entry on the Marvel Wikia**

---

**Here is Reed Richard's first attempt at breaching dimensional barriers/interfaces that lead to the discovery of the Microverse, Underspace and Overspace. Hank Pym expanded (pardon the pun) his ideas from Reed's early explorations.**

[image]

**Image clips are from Mighty Avengers #30 and Fantastic Four Vol 1, #16.**

Comment: Just so I understand... it's a function of the Pym particles rather than purely a mechanism of growing/shrinking?  Or could anyone who grew or shrank without limit visit these places?

Comment: It is a property of his long-term relationship with the Pym particles and the ability to shrink into the Underverse and then once there, growing into the abstract realm of the Oververse.